# Currency Convertor Web Service wont work

Tags: asp.net

I want to use the Currency Convertor at http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl. But it isnt working I get nothing in the dropdownlist menus.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using com.webservicex.www;

public partial class cc : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //using web service at http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl
        double rate = 0, result = 0;
        Currency curr1, curr2;
        try
        {
            CurrencyConvertor ws = new CurrencyConvertor();
            curr1 = (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
            curr2 = (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
            rate = ws.ConversionRate(curr1, curr2);
            result = System.Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) * rate;
            Label2.Text = "The exchange rate between" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + " and " + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + " is " + rate;
            Label3.Text = "Converted " + TextBox1.Text + " to " + result;
        }
        catch
        {
            Label2.Text = "Web service not available please try again later."; 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see you populating your dropdownlists anywhere

Comment: Could you elaborate please, this is my first time using services.

Comment: The call to the webservice returns a conversion rate that has nothing to do with populating your dropdownlists.

Comment: the dropdown lists hold the conversions IE: USD, GBP etc..

Comment: In your question you said "it isnt working I get nothing in the dropdownlist menus."

Comment: Yeah the web service holds all of the currency codes, they should be populated into a dropdownlist, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11350/discussion-between-user1389384-and-gratzy)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to avoid calling the web service each time you want to display a dropdown menu. The choice of currencies simply doesn't change very often. (And you need to be prepared to deal with errors anyway.)

Rather, download the data available once up front and store it in an XML file suitable for backing a dropdown list:

```
<Currencies>
     <currency Name="EUR" />
     <currency Name="RUB" />
```

Then, have ASP.NET code as follows:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"
        DataFile="~/Currencies.xml">
</asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
        DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I would, but I am under strict instructions to use the web service for everything.

Comment: Bad luck then. Especially as the web service is really slow ... [five seconds to get a conversion rate](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=EUR&ToCurrency=RUB) ...